# *ngIf="name.invalid" doesn't work with Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material

When I put this:

```
<textarea #name="ngModel" class="form-control" id="" cols="30" rows="3" style="resize:none" required></textarea>
<div *ngIf="name.invalid" class="alert alert-danger">
     <div *ngIf="name.errors.required">
            Name is required.
      </div>
</div>
```

I got this when the view starts: (It's ok, I want something like this but in Angular Material...)
[image]

And, when I put this (Angular Material):

```
<mat-form-field>
  <textarea matInput #name="ngModel" class="form-control" id="" cols="30" rows="3" style="resize:none" required></textarea>
  <mat-error *ngIf="name.invalid">Name is required.</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

I got this:

[image]

It's obviusly invalid but nothing happens, no red. The `<mat-error>` appears when manually i focus and blur that textarea. I want that this textarea shows invalid like this at the start:
[image]

What can I do? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mat-error` element only becomes visible through the form field control failing validation.

Angular material uses default [ErrorStateMatcher](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/53b01bcab20a8c39a8bbbe5cafe2c1cc3ab3812e/src/lib/core/error/error-options.ts#L21) to check whether that control is valid:

```typescript
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class ErrorStateMatcher {
  isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
    return !!(control && control.invalid && (control.touched || (form && form.submitted)));
  }
}
```

As you can see it will only fail if control is touched or form is submitted.

You can override this behavior by using `errorStateMatcher` input on your control:

**html**

```typescript
<textarea matInput ... [errorStateMatcher]="matcher" required></textarea>
```

**ts**

```typescript
import {ErrorStateMatcher} from '@angular/material/core';

export class MyErrorStateMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {
  isErrorState(
       control: FormControl | null,
       form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
    return control && control.invalid;
  }
} 

@Component({
  ...
})
export class AppComponent  {

  matcher = new MyErrorStateMatcher()
}
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/FAYlob8eFSIAccWZUyUh?open=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!! I was looking for a long time for a problem similar to mine and I could not find it. Seriously thanks.